# Liferay - persist friendly URL

Tags: liferay, portlet, spring-webflow

I have single page with two portlets, first portet show some content base on frindly URL like **localhost:8080/portal/web/guest/article/-/id/123**. Second portlet is form. When I send the form, I expect that my page is reloaded and url looks like **portal/web/guest/article/-/id/123?p_p_id=xxx&p_p_lifecycle=0&p_p_state=normal** but my friendly parameter(**/-/id/123**) is gone. Can somone help me?

*article-url-routes.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE routes PUBLIC "-//Liferay//DTD Friendly URL Routes 6.2.0//EN" "http://www.liferay.com/dtd/liferay-friendly-url-routes_6_2_0.dtd">

<routes>
    <route>
        <pattern>/{id:[0-9]+}</pattern>
        <generated-parameter name="id">{id}</generated-parameter>
    </route>
</routes>
```

liferay-portlet.xml

```
<portlet>
    <portlet-name>Foo</portlet-name>
    <friendly-url-mapper-class>com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.DefaultFriendlyURLMapper</friendly-url-mapper-class>
    <friendly-url-mapping>id</friendly-url-mapping>
    <friendly-url-routes>article-url-routes.xml</friendly-url-routes>
</portlet>
```

Comment: I guess your form portlet uses an ActionURL to submit data. HAs this ActionURL a redirect parameter?

Comment: No only 
`<portlet:actionURL var="actionUrl">
    <portlet:param name="execution" value="${flowExecutionKey}"/>
</portlet:actionURL>`